# Error during template compile of 'reducers': Expression form not supported

Tags: angular, ngrx

The error in the title shows everytime I try to build for production. The error shows in the below code in index.ts:

```
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
  auth: fromAuth.reducer,
/*other stuff here ....*/
};
```

I searched in google, but I couldn't find a post with the same error related to reducers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How do your reducers look like?

If it's something like the following you'll have to refactor it to make it work with AOT compilation (for now, because it's possible with Angular 9).

```
export const reducer = createReducer()

// refactor to:

const privateReducer = createReducer()

export function reducer(state, action) {
  return privateReducer(state, action)
}
```